# Nuke - Matrix4 camera constraint lock Z rotation

Tags: c++, matrix, camera, constraints, nuke

So im building a plugin in Nuke (from The Foundry) that will mimic Maya's animation constraint behaviours. I have a parent, a child, and then options for point, orientation, aim, parent constraints. This is all working pretty well, however my biggest issue at the moment is the Aim constraint.

Some background:
Working with the Nuke [Matrix4 class](http://docs.thefoundry.co.uk/nuke/90/ndkreference/Plugins/classDD_1_1Image_1_1Matrix4.html)
Its worth noting this matrix is a 4x4 in which the first 3 columns of the first 3 rows apply to rotations/scale, and the last column of the first 3 rows is translation (X,Y,Z)

in [Vector3 classes](http://docs.thefoundry.co.uk/nuke/90/ndkreference/Plugins/classDD_1_1Image_1_1Vector3.html)
I am getting the source and target position. Target-source = ST
Then im setting up a Y plane (one inverted, one not)
Then i get the corss product of my ST point and the Y plane, and then another cross product of my ST and inverted Y plane. (for when the parent is behind the child to invert it)
I then get the cross product of my ST and the result of my ST.cross(y_plane)

The aim constraint actually works quite well, but i get a lot of Z rotation in my camera (child) when the parent is in certain postions. I want to be able to avoid this Z rotation. Would anyone happen to know how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

If you're emulating Maya's constraint system, Maya handles Z rotation through the `up vector`, which adjusts your Z rotation to align with one of five options:

- `scene up` aims the top of your camera to `+Y`
- `object up` aims the top of your camera toward a third object
- `object rotation up` matches the camera's Z rotation to the `XYZ` rotation of a third object
- `vector` aims the top of your camera at that vector
- `none` Doesn't attempt to orient the top of your camera with anything. This must be what you have currently.

Additionally, there's an `up vector` which defines what is the "top of your camera" just like the `aim vector` defines where the camera should point.

Comment: This is great info -do you have any reading material to help me implement it? Im not sure how/where to plug this in. Thanks!

Comment: I wish I did. I would imagine it's a bit like having a second constraint which only affects Z rotation, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Let me know when you finish your plugin. I'd love to have a constraint system in Nuke :)

Comment: Hey - its finished and fantastic thanks to the help! - Unfortunately its built for my company, and I cant share it :(

Comment: No worries. Congrats on finishing it! Sounds like a great tool